# Trigger click on keypress on hovered element

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, keypress

I'd like to know if there is any way that I can get the element the mouse is currently hovering over when pressing any key.

I didn't seem to find anything like that.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead windows events:

```js
var positionHovered = []

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
       positionHovered = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
})

document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
console.clear();
console.log(document.elementFromPoint(positionHovered[0], positionHovered[1]).id);
});
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

div:hover{
  background-color: #dedede;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a semi good working work around by combining two events

First you need the mousemove event on the window to track the cursor position:

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
       window.pos = [e.clientX, e.clientY]; // here we just save the last cursor position inside the window object in a new property, so we can access it globally
})
```

Then we will need another Event Listener for triggering a keyboard event, like keydown:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
       // using the elementFromPoint method to determine what the element is under the cursor, by accessing our saved position
       console.log(document.elementFromPoint(window.pos[0], window.pos[1]))

});
```

This in combination is working alright, but i dont know what the browser support is for the method `elementFromPoint(x,y)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `mouseover` event to the elements that you want to hover over, and then add the `keydown` event listener to call a custom function.  In that function you can use a query selector to get the hovered element, and use it in your code. You can then remove the `keydown` event listener on `mouseout`.

```js
window.focus();

document.querySelectorAll(`.hover-div`).forEach(elmnt => {
  elmnt.addEventListener(`mouseover`, (event) => {
    document.addEventListener(`keydown`, logElement)
  });
  elmnt.addEventListener(`mouseout`, (event) => {
    console.clear();
    document.removeEventListener(`keydown`, logElement)
  })
});

function logElement() {
  const elem = document.querySelector(`.hover-div:hover`); 
  console.log(elem.outerHTML)
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #e2e1e0;
}

div.container div {
  background: white;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}

.hover-div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hover-div" title="div-1">1</div>
  <div class="hover-div" title="div-2">2</div>
  <div class="hover-div" title="div-3">3</div>
</div>
```